# Substitution for 'still going on'

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the one word substitute for 'still going on' as in a question like ,' Did the class end or its still going on'?

Comment: "its" should be "is it".  "continuing" might work for "still going on".  Is this a crossword puzzle?

Answer (score 1):

One possible word might be "ongoing," though that could also imply an event happening at an unspecified future time as well. Is there a specific reason for needing the single word? "...or is it still going on?" is perfectly acceptable English.

Comment: Thanks! I presumed that it's just a translation of what I would say in my mother tongue.